# Understanding R's anyDuplicated

Tags: r

Quick question in understanding's R's anyDuplicated, when passed on a dataframe (lets say x y z columns with 1k observations) will if check if any of the rows has the exact same x y z values as another row in the same dataframe? Thanks

Comment: Did reading `help(anyDuplicated)` not answer your question?

Comment: I did, this is the part i don't understand ".. are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts"

Comment: A smaller subscript just means a previous row.  So `anyDuplicated(rbind(mtcars, mtcars[1, ]))` tells you that row 33 is a duplicate of some previous row.

Comment: Doesn't that mean he checks if the first row is a duplicate of the second, then if the third is a a duplicate of the first and the second?

Comment: Just read the source code of `anyDuplicated.data.frame`.  It pastes the rows together, then runs `anyDuplicated.default` on it.

Comment: Hmm ok, any suggestions on achieving what i want to do? Thanks for your time

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I have a file with 6 columns and about 2M observations which i need to clean, since each observation is unique, i need to check for duplicates of the whole dataframe (not even sure what i'll do if i find them yet) but all the answers i found aren't really working out

Comment: I would use `my_duplicates <- duplicated(my_data) | duplicated(my_data, fromLast = TRUE)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune correct me if i'm wrong, that would check from first to last for duplicates then from the last to first?

Comment: Yes that is the idea. There should really be a function that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `duplicated` and combine it from front to back.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = c(1:3,1,1), y = c(3:5,3,3))
mydf
#   x y
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
# 3 3 5
# 4 1 3
# 5 1 3
```

There three duplicated rows 1, 4, and 5. But 'duplicated' will only mark what is duplicated not the original value also.

```
duplicated(mydf)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
duplicated(mydf, fromLast = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Using from last looks from the end to front to include the original value. By the way, I will ask the R core team to add a unified function to do both.

```
myduplicates <- duplicated(mydf) | duplicated(mydf, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Saving the expression as a variable allows us to count and subset later.

```
sum(myduplicates)
#[1] 3
mydf[myduplicates,]
#   x y
# 1 1 3
# 4 1 3
# 5 1 3
mydf[!myduplicates,]
#   x y
# 2 2 4
# 3 3 5
```